# ECB: can't access /

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-ecb

On updating to Kubuntu 12.04, and Emacs 24.1.50 - I can't access `/` folder in ecb's tree browser. When I try to get there, or just activate the ecb Emacs opens `*tramp/scpc C*` buffer and it says:

```
 ssh: Could not resolve hostname C: Name or service not known
```

it was working fine before the update to Kubuntu 12.04 and Emacs 24.1.50

All my ecb-related configs:

```lisp
;; ECB and CEDET:
;; (global-ede-mode 1)
(require 'semantic/sb)
(require 'semantic/analyze)
(provide 'semantic-analyze)
(provide 'semantic-ctxt)
(provide 'semanticdb)
(provide 'semanticdb-find)
(provide 'semanticdb-mode)
(provide 'semantic-load)
(semantic-mode 1)
(setq semantic-load-turn-useful-things-on t)

(setq stack-trace-on-error t)

(require 'cedet)

(require 'ecb)
;; (ecb-activate)
;; (ecb-byte-compile)
(require 'ecb-autoloads) ;; if aren't going to turn ECB on at start up
(setq ecb-auto-activate 1) 

(ecb-winman-winring-enable-support) ;; This MUST be done BEFORE the first call to any winring-command, so also before calling winring-initialize! 

(setq ecb-winman-winring-name "ECB")

(global-set-key (kbd "C-x e") '(lambda () 
                                 (interactive)
                                 (ecb-activate)
                                 ))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x E") 'ecb-deactivate)

(setq tags-revert-without-query t)

(setq ecb-cache-directory-contents nil)
(setq ecb-highlight-tag-with-point t)

(setq semantic-idle-work-parse-neighboring-files-flag nil)
(setq semantic-idle-work-update-headers-flag nil)

(setq global-semanticdb-minor-mode nil)
;; (setq semantic-imenu-index-directory nil) ;; do I have such a var at all?
(require 'semantic-load)

;; (global-semantic-auto-parse-mode -1)
(global-semantic-show-unmatched-syntax-mode -1)
(setq truncate-partial-width-windows nil)

(setq global-semantic-idle-summary-mode t)
(setq global-semantic-idle-completions-mode t)
(setq global-semantic-decoration-mode t)
(setq global-semantic-highlight-func-mode t)

(add-hook 'ecb-symboldef-buffer-sync (lambda ()
                                       (setq truncate-lines nil)
                                       ))

;; etags!
(setq tags-file-name (expand-file-name "~/its/dbes/etgs/TAGS"))

(setq ecb-highlight-tag-with-point (quote highlight-scroll))
(setq ecb-layout-name "left-symboldef")
(setq ecb-layout-window-sizes (quote (("left-symboldef" (0.2571428571428571 . 0.26666666666666666) (0.2571428571428571 . 0.2) (0.2571428571428571 . 0.23333333333333334) (0.2571428571428571 . 0.26666666666666666)) ("left8" (0.23809523809523808 . 0.2857142857142857) (0.23809523809523808 . 0.21428571428571427) (0.23809523809523808 . 0.2857142857142857) (0.23809523809523808 . 0.17857142857142858)))))
(setq ecb-options-version "2.40")
(setq ecb-source-path (quote (("/home/boris/its/plts" "plts"))))
(setq ecb-tip-of-the-day nil)
(setq ecb-tree-incremental-search (quote substring))
```

as You see - no `C:` in there.

**Edit 2**:

I've found to have a `~/.emacs.d/tramp` file, and it has:

```
;; -*- emacs-lisp -*- <12/05/03 19:12:12 /home/boris/.emacs.d/tramp>
;; Tramp connection history.  Don't change this file.
;; You can delete it, forcing Tramp to reapply the checks.

((["scpc" nil "C" nil]
  nil))
```

I've deleted that file, then have opened the emacs, have activated ECB, tried to get to `/` in the directory tree, it made the same error. Then, after I've close emacs - it made the same `tramp` file. Seems like it is writter somewhere in a tramp - in the latest emacs sources.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Kubuntu 12.04 and ran into this same problem; don't know if it is specific to Kubuntu or 12.04 generally.

Somehow the "C:\nppdf32Log\debuglog.txt" file (http://askubuntu.com/questions/144408/what-is-the-file-c-nppdf32log-debuglog-txt) was being picked up by the internal ecb-filename-cache - I couldn't figure out exactly how ecb-filename-cache was being populated but I was able to see this by running ecb-remote-patch-cache-dump - this was the source of the tramp error for me.  To get around it, I removed all semantic cache directories, all traces of the debuglog.txt file and any tramp files that I could find.  Viola, ECB works again.

Answer (score 1):

Weird, maybe it's reusing an old C:\ something in your old trammp file?  also reading this [scpc link](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#index-method-scpc-67) maybe your newly updated kubuntu doesn't support it?  Try the command the link says to see if it works.  Sounds more like a tramp issue than an ECB.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, and found that customizing the source path (as noted in [ECB First Steps](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/docs/First-steps.html)) fixed the problem for me.